# How can I make hybrid graphics(AMD/Intel) work on Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

I own a HP ProBook 450 G0 laptop, running Ubuntu 14.04 (3.16.0-33-generic x86_64). This particular laptop has two GPUs and I want to be able to switch between them. I'm looking for a free driver or utility that would allow me achieve this, but I'm wiling to install proprietary software if no other solution applies.

Things I have tried so far:

- I tried locating `vga_switcheroo`, but file `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` is not present on my system.
- I downloaded the official AMD drivers and tried installing them using aptitude, but it didn't complete the installation because of a missing dependency (`fglrx-core`).
- I found out I am able to disable the discrete graphics card in BIOS.

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

Output of `lshw -C display`:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

Comment: Where did you download the drivers from, and how did you try installing them - and what is the output of `sudo lshw -C display`?. From the `lspci` output I can only see one Intel graphics card, are you sure there is a AMD card and that it is enabled in BIOS? Also you can use the Additional Drivers window to install the proprietary  fglrx drivers.

Comment: Once you have the AMD card enabled with a driver (doesn't have to be fglrx, the open source ones can work better), you should be able to use [vga_switcheroo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hybrid_graphics) if you have a kernel older than 3.11 - otherwise it is managed by [Radeon DPM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/324733/how-to-enable-the-radeon-dynamic-power-management-feature)

Comment: Thank you for your help! There were several things wrong: When I gave up trying to install fglrx I didn't remove all of the fglrx packages. After I had fixed that, I spent an hour trying to figure out why it still doesn't work and then I realised that you have to use sudo :D Please, consider adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the lspci output I can only see one Intel graphics card, make sure there is a AMD card and that it is enabled in BIOS. Also you can use the Additional Drivers window to install the proprietary fglrx drivers:
[image]

If that or installing `fglrx`/`fglrx-updates` does not work, you can download the drivers from [AMD's site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064) ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) may help there - I will add that when I had to do this recently I had to purge the existing fglrx install from the repo and `ocl-icd-libopencl1`)

Once you have the AMD card enabled with a driver (doesn't have to be fglrx, the open source ones can work better), you *might* be able to use [vga_switcheroo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hybrid_graphics) if you have a kernel older than 3.11 - otherwise it may be managed by [Radeon DPM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324733/how-to-enable-the-radeon-dynamic-power-management-feature).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a bug in the `fglrx` packet. As J0nDaFr3aK noted in [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266268&page=4), the following lines are a viable workaround.

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese*
sudo apt-get install xorg-video-abi-15
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem with a similar radeon graphic card.

i installed the mainline kernel version 4.6 from here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/

Here is a guide for the installation:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Verifying_the_mainline_build_binaries

After booting the new kernel, i tested the card with the following command, and the changing to the radeon graphic card was working:

$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info

this answer i also posted here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/778205/16-04-radeon-r7-m260-errors/780515#780515